# configure: error: Cannot build Qt apps, probably due to missing or too old Qt packages

Tags: macos, qt, config, omnet++

thanks for watching my problem. When I want to implement OMNET++5.4.1 on my mac OS (10.13.6) with command ./configure, I encounter the following problems:

configure: error: Cannot build Qt apps, probably due to missing or too old Qt packages. Make sure Qt development packages are installed and newer than Qt 5.4. You can disable Qtenv by setting the WITH_QTENV variable to "no" in configure.user.

If I set the WITH_QTENV variable to “no”, then the configure does succeeds, but I could not use the IDE, and also the test command ./aloha has the following error

Error: The simulation wanted to ask a question, set cmdenv-interactive=true to allow it: "Enter parameter 'Aloha.host[0].iaTime' (unassigned):" -- in module (aloha::Host) Aloha.host[0] (id=3), during network setup.

Anyone can help me fix the problem? thanks very much.

Comment: The error says "Cannot build Qt apps, probably due to missing or too old Qt packages." - Have you tried to install or to update them?

Answer (score 1):

This is outdated, but in case anyone comes across this issue, having spaces in the full path to Omnet++'s root folder raises this issue for some reason on macOS. Removing any and all spaces from the parent folders solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem even though I had updated Qt.

In my case, I had a folder in the OMNeT++ path with a space in the name.

After removing the spaces from any directory in the path I just restarted the `. setenv` and `./configure` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you source the setenv script, before running ./configure.

```
$ . setenv
```

All necessary dependencies (including QT libs) are bundled with OMNeT++. Other possible cause is that the dependencies (in the /tools) folder are not present or extracted for some reason... (corrupted install package etc.)

Note that the dependencies extracted on the first run of the setenv script.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I tried what Rudi said and succeed.

We can see that in the official installation guide of omnet++, it is necessary to close the terminal after the command:

```
$. setenv
```

for the edition of `~/.bashrc` to come  into effect.

However, after we close the terminal, `$. setenv` is lost. So just type this command again will be alright.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue in windows.
Solution is to install in c drive

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to set WITH_QTENV in the configure.user file to no.